# How to get GridView scroll to top using keyboard in Android TV

Tags: android, gridview, focus, google-tv

I am developing apps on Android smart TV, which can only use remote controller to navigate the focus position(just like using d-pad key in normal android devices).

I used `GridView` to display images. The problem is when scrolled to bottom, it cannot be scrolled up any more! I know this phenomena will never happen in touch mode device, but for Android TV it is really common.

Actually, I faced the same problem when I using `ListView`, and I solved it by scrolling to the upper row manually. Override `AbsListView.OnScrollListener`:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
        int totalItemCount) {
    try {
        if (firstVisibleItem > 0 
                && view.getChildAt(0).isSelected()
                || view.getChildAt(0).hasFocus()) {
            view.smoothScrollToPosition(firstVisibleItem - 1);
            Log.d(TAG, "scroll up");
        } else if ((firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) < totalItemCount
                && view.getChildAt(visibleItemCount-1).hasFocus()
                || view.getChildAt(visibleItemCount-1).isSelected()) {
            view.smoothScrollToPosition(firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount + 1);
            Log.d(TAG, "scroll down");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(),e);
    }
}
```

As you know, there is a BIG difference between `ListView` and `GridView`, that is `GridView` has mulit-column items. So, when focus on the first row(not the first row of adapter data), the focused item not always be the `firstVisibleItem`, and the code above not work anymore.

**EDIT:** The reason why `ListView` and `GridView` cannot scroll up is the mount height of  all visible items exactly equals their parent's height. When D-UP key press, the focus move to the widget above `GridView` instead of the upper items.

I tried this:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    if (firstVisibleItem > 0 && isFocusOnFirstRow()) {
        view.smoothScrollToPosition(firstVisibleItem - 1);
        Log.d(TAG, "scroll up");
    }
}

private boolean isFocusOnFirstRow() {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < mGridView.getNumColumns(); i++) {
            if (mGridView.getChildAt(i).hasFocus()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    } 
    return false;
}
```

But not working. Can anybody give some advices?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: iStar did you solve this? I'm unsure if my issue is similar to yours - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870223/keyboard-navigation-with-android-gridview-doesnt-scroll-grid

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea that might work for you. If instead of scrolling the grid view you simply destroy it and recreate it when you want to jump to the top that might work. How ever for the case where you want to allow the user to scroll it requires a different approach. I recommend that you offset the grid view such that its elements are not perfectly aligned with the parent. For example, if you had the bottom visible row only half showing (cut off half way) it indicates to the user that there is more items to scroll down too. The same would apply as you scroll up - the top row would only be half showing (top of the items cut). This is a pattern that I see a lot for TV apps.