# Keyboard navigation with Android GridView doesn't scroll grid

Tags: android, gridview, focus

I'm trying to use a keyboard to navigate through a GridView of items.

In the short demo, which only contains a GridView (containing item views with `android:focusable="true"`), you can see that none of the items gain focus - the grid is the thing that scrolls (the items don't turn orange).

[image: scrolling short demo]

Adding the `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"` allows each item to be focused first, but still, doesn't continue to scroll the GridView so you can navigate down:

[image: with descendent focusability set]

Clicking on an item (with mouse or by pressing Return if the item was focused, after the descendent focusability fix) turns an item blue - indicating it's in pressed state.

[image: clicking grid items]

@layout/activity_my.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/listview"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:numColumns="2" />
```

@layout/dummy_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/dummy_item_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="150dp"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:focusable="true"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:background="@drawable/item_background" />
```

@drawable/item_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
  <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
</selector>
```

MyActivity.java (with ListAdapter):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        AbsListView listview = (AbsListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listview.setAdapter(new DummyAdapter(getLayoutInflater()));
    }

    private static class DummyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private static final int COUNT = 25;

        private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        DummyAdapter(LayoutInflater layoutInflater) {
            this.layoutInflater = layoutInflater;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return "Item " + position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy_item, parent, false);
            }
            ((TextView) view).setText(getItem(position));
            return view;
        }

    }

}
```

Swapping the GridView for a ListView, without changing the adapter, or the item views/item view attributes, will behave as expected - items can be focused and the ListView will scroll to the bottom, so that all items can be focused using just keyboard input. Also, using a RecyclerView with LinearLayoutManager / GridLayoutManager will also work correctly.

I have tried this on API 16 and 22 with the same results. I have tried settings the `android:descendantFocusability` attribute on the GridView to `afterDescendents` with the same result.

Comment: I would use a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager (and an ItemDecoration, that takes into account item spans, for item spacing) to implement such a screen. This question is just for curiosity!

Comment: Have you tried `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"`?

Comment: @manu thanks for the reply. The issue isn't with the selector/focus, it's with not being able to scroll (you can see in the second gif, I'm able to see the selector, but still not able to scroll).

Comment: is there a way i could get this demo project so i see what i can do

Comment: @Elltz sure, I have [a branch on a spiking repo](https://github.com/ataulm/android-basic/tree/gridview) which can be checked out and run using `./gradlew clean build`

Comment: I have this same issue using RecyclerView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it doesn't work with GridView, as you said, but i have some issue also with `ListView`. The `ListView` scrolls correctly, but only the first item of every page is highlighted.

With these little modifications you can achieve the effect you want on both GridView and ListView.

Remove `android:descendantFocusability` in activity_my.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="2" />
```

Remove `android:focusable` in dummy_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dummy_item_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/item_background" />
```

Change from `android:state_focused` to `android:state_selected` in item_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_light" />
</selector>
```

Comment: state selected is different from state focused though - consider also the case where you want to represent items that are actually selected, e.g. in multi select mode: you'll also need to have `selected`, `focused` and `selected+focused` states to be accessible.

Comment: this does highlight that GridView is just rubbish though - it shouldn't be selecting items (`view.setSelected(true)`) as you move through the Grid, but this is a good solution (using selected state) - could rely on `state_checked` for when you actually want to select an item, implementing Checkable on the ItemView, and `view.setChecked(true)` where you would do setSelected. Thanks!

Comment: one final comment - I was wrong - `selected` is the same, conceptually, as `focused` - in the source code, they (Google) even apologise for the naming! `setActivated(boolean)` is the one that I imagined would be `setSelected(boolean)`.